# Render Tapestry page and get it as Stream/String resource

Tags: java, tapestry

Is any convinient way to dynamically render some page inside application and then retrieve its contents as `InputStream` or `String`?

For example, the simplest way is:

```
        // generate url
        Link link = linkSource.createPageRenderLink("SomePageLink");
        String urlAsString = link.toAbsoluteURI() + "/customParam/" + customParamValue;

        // get info stream from url
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urlAsString);
        httpGet.addHeader("cookie", request.getHeader("cookie"));
        HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpGet);
        InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
        ...
```

But it seems it must be some more easy method how to archive the same result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I created [tapestry-offline](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-offline) for exactly this purpose. Please be aware of the issue [here](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-offline/issues/4) (workaround included).

It's probably best to understand your exact use case. If, for example, you are generating emails in a scheduled task, it's probably better to configure [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) or [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to hit a URL.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably also worth mentioning the [capture](http://t5stitch-lazan.rhcloud.com/capturedemo) component from [tapestry-stitch](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-stitch)

This is only useful in situations where you want to cature part of a page as a String during page / component render.